# COTURN Server not reachable

Tags: webrtc, coturn, turn

I am running a coturn server on my system,and am having trouble accessing it.

The coturn server configuration is provided below. Note that the addresses for the relay-ip and the listenoing-ip are set to localhost (127.0.0.1). Other settings conform to the documentation.

What happens is that any attempts to access the server -- even from localhost (http://127.0.0.1:3478 or turn://127.0.0.1:3478) -- get a "cannot connect to server" response. I look at the logs and am seeing no errors in the startup or running of the server.

Is there some change I need to make in the configuration that will enable connections to this coturn server?

```
# Coturn TURN SERVER configuration file
#
# Boolean values note: where a boolean value is supposed to be used,
# you can use '0', 'off', 'no', 'false', or 'f' as 'false',
# and you can use '1', 'on', 'yes', 'true', or 't' as 'true'
# If the value is missing, then it means 'true' by default.
#

# Listener interface device (optional, Linux only).
# NOT RECOMMENDED.
#
#listening-device=eth0

# TURN listener port for UDP and TCP (Default: 3478).
# Note: actually, TLS & DTLS sessions can connect to the
# "plain" TCP & UDP port(s), too - if allowed by configuration.
#
listening-port=3478

# TURN listener port for TLS (Default: 5349).
# Note: actually, "plain" TCP & UDP sessions can connect to the TLS & DTLS
# port(s), too - if allowed by configuration. The TURN server
# "automatically" recognizes the type of traffic. Actually, two listening
# endpoints (the "plain" one and the "tls" one) are equivalent in terms of
# functionality; but Coturn keeps both endpoints to satisfy the RFC 5766 specs.
# For secure TCP connections, Coturn currently supports SSL version 3 and
# TLS version 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2.
# For secure UDP connections, Coturn supports DTLS version 1.
#
tls-listening-port=5349

# Alternative listening port for UDP and TCP listeners;
# default (or zero) value means "listening port plus one".
# This is needed for RFC 5780 support
# (STUN extension specs, NAT behavior discovery). The TURN Server
# supports RFC 5780 only if it is started with more than one
# listening IP address of the same family (IPv4 or IPv6).
# RFC 5780 is supported only by UDP protocol, other protocols
# are listening to that endpoint only for "symmetry".
#
#alt-listening-port=0

# Alternative listening port for TLS and DTLS protocols.
# Default (or zero) value means "TLS listening port plus one".
#
#alt-tls-listening-port=0

# Some network setups will require using a TCP reverse proxy in front
# of the STUN server. If the proxy port option is set a single listener
# is started on the given port that accepts connections using the
# haproxy proxy protocol v2.
# (https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/doc/proxy-protocol.txt)
#
#tcp-proxy-port=5555

# Listener IP address of relay server. Multiple listeners can be specified.
# If no IP(s) specified in the config file or in the command line options,
# then all IPv4 and IPv6 system IPs will be used for listening.
#
listening-ip=127.0.0.1
#listening-ip=10.207.21.238
#listening-ip=2607:f0d0:1002:51::4

# Auxiliary STUN/TURN server listening endpoint.
# Aux servers have almost full TURN and STUN functionality.
# The (minor) limitations are:
#
# 1) Auxiliary servers do not have alternative ports and
# they do not support STUN RFC 5780 functionality (CHANGE REQUEST).
#
# 2) Auxiliary servers also are never returning ALTERNATIVE-SERVER reply.
#
# Valid formats are 1.2.3.4:5555 for IPv4 and [1:2::3:4]:5555 for IPv6.
#
# There may be multiple aux-server options, each will be used for listening
# to client requests.
#
#aux-server=172.17.19.110:33478
#aux-server=[2607:f0d0:1002:51::4]:33478

# (recommended for older Linuxes only)
# Automatically balance UDP traffic over auxiliary servers (if configured).
# The load balancing is using the ALTERNATE-SERVER mechanism.
# The TURN client must support 300 ALTERNATE-SERVER response for this
# functionality.
#
#udp-self-balance

# Relay interface device for relay sockets (optional, Linux only).
# NOT RECOMMENDED.
#
#relay-device=eth1

# Relay address (the local IP address that will be used to relay the
# packets to the peer).
# Multiple relay addresses may be used.
# The same IP(s) can be used as both listening IP(s) and relay IP(s).
#
# If no relay IP(s) specified, then the turnserver will apply the default
# policy: it will decide itself which relay addresses to be used, and it
# will always be using the client socket IP address as the relay IP address
# of the TURN session (if the requested relay address family is the same
# as the family of the client socket).
#
relay-ip=127.0.0.1
#relay-ip=2607:f0d0:1002:51::5

# For Amazon EC2 users:
#
# TURN Server public/private address mapping, if the server is behind NAT.
# In that situation, if a -X is used in form "-X <ip>" then that ip will be     reported
# as relay IP address of all allocations. This scenario works only in a simple case
# when one single relay address is be used, and no RFC5780 functionality is required.
# That single relay address must be mapped by NAT to the 'external' IP.
# The "external-ip" value, if not empty, is returned in XOR-RELAYED-ADDRESS field.
# For that 'external' IP, NAT must forward ports directly (relayed port 12345
# must be always mapped to the same 'external' port 12345).
#
# In more complex case when more than one IP address is involved,
# that option must be used several times, each entry must
# have form "-X <public-ip/private-ip>", to map all involved addresses.
# RFC5780 NAT discovery STUN functionality will work correctly,
# if the addresses are mapped properly, even when the TURN server itself
# is behind A NAT.
#
# By default, this value is empty, and no address mapping is used.
#
#external-ip=60.70.80.91
#
#OR:
#
#external-ip=60.70.80.91/172.17.19.101
#external-ip=60.70.80.92/172.17.19.102


# Number of the relay threads to handle the established connections
# (in addition to authentication thread and the listener thread).
# If explicitly set to 0 then application runs relay process in a
# single thread, in the same thread with the listener process
# (the authentication thread will still be a separate thread).
#
# If this parameter is not set, then the default OS-dependent
# thread pattern algorithm will be employed. Usually the default
# algorithm is optimal, so you have to change this option
# if you want to make some fine tweaks.
#
# In the older systems (Linux kernel before 3.9),
# the number of UDP threads is always one thread per network listening
# endpoint - including the auxiliary endpoints - unless 0 (zero) or
# 1 (one) value is set.
#
#relay-threads=0

# Lower and upper bounds of the UDP relay endpoints:
# (default values are 49152 and 65535)
#
#min-port=49152
#max-port=65535

# Uncomment to run TURN server in 'normal' 'moderate' verbose mode.
# By default the verbose mode is off.
#verbose

# Uncomment to run TURN server in 'extra' verbose mode.
# This mode is very annoying and produces lots of output.
# Not recommended under normal circumstances.
#
#Verbose

# Uncomment to use fingerprints in the TURN messages.
# By default the fingerprints are off.
#
fingerprint

# Uncomment to use long-term credential mechanism.
# By default no credentials mechanism is used (any user allowed).
#
lt-cred-mech

# This option is the opposite of lt-cred-mech.
# (TURN Server with no-auth option allows anonymous access).
# If neither option is defined, and no users are defined,
# then no-auth is default. If at least one user is defined,
# in this file, in command line or in usersdb file, then
# lt-cred-mech is default.
#
#no-auth

# Enable prometheus exporter
# If enabled the turnserver will expose an endpoint with stats on a prometheus format
# this endpoint is listening on a different port to not conflict with other configurations.
#
# You can simply run the turnserver and access the port 9641 and path /metrics
#
# For more info on the prometheus exporter and metrics
# https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/
# https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/data_model/
#
#prometheus

# TURN REST API flag.
# (Time Limited Long Term Credential)
# Flag that sets a special authorization option that is based upon authentication secret.
#
# This feature's purpose is to support "TURN Server REST API", see
# "TURN REST API" link in the project's page
# https://github.com/coturn/coturn/
#
# This option is used with timestamp:
#
# usercombo -> "timestamp:userid"
# turn user -> usercombo
# turn password -> base64(hmac(secret key, usercombo))
#
# This allows TURN credentials to be accounted for a specific user id.
# If you don't have a suitable id, then the timestamp alone can be used.
# This option is enabled by turning on secret-based authentication.
# The actual value of the secret is defined either by the option static-auth-secret,
# or can be found in the turn_secret table in the database (see below).
#
# Read more about it:
#  - https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-uberti-behave-turn-rest-00
#  - https://www.ietf.org/proceedings/87/slides/slides-87-behave-10.pdf
#
# Be aware that use-auth-secret overrides some parts of lt-cred-mech.
# The use-auth-secret feature depends internally on lt-cred-mech, so if you set
# this option then it automatically enables lt-cred-mech internally
# as if you had enabled both.
#
# Note that you can use only one auth mechanism at the same time! This is because,
# both mechanisms conduct username and password validation in different ways.
#
# Use either lt-cred-mech or use-auth-secret in the conf
# to avoid any confusion.
#
use-auth-secret

# 'Static' authentication secret value (a string) for TURN REST API only.
# If not set, then the turn server
# will try to use the 'dynamic' value in the turn_secret table
# in the user database (if present). The database-stored  value can be changed on-the-fly
# by a separate program, so this is why that mode is considered 'dynamic'.
#
static-auth-secret=<REDACTED>

# Server name used for
# the oAuth authentication purposes.
# The default value is the realm name.
#
#server-name=blackdow.carleon.gov

# Flag that allows oAuth authentication.
#
#oauth

# 'Static' user accounts for the long term credentials mechanism, only.
# This option cannot be used with TURN REST API.
# 'Static' user accounts are NOT dynamically checked by the turnserver process,
# so they can NOT be changed while the turnserver is running.
#
#user=username1:key1
#user=username2:key2
# OR:
#user=username1:password1
#user=username2:password2
#
# Keys must be generated by turnadmin utility. The key value depends
# on user name, realm, and password:
#
# Example:
# $ turnadmin -k -u ninefingers -r north.gov -p youhavetoberealistic
# Output: 0xbc807ee29df3c9ffa736523fb2c4e8ee
# ('0x' in the beginning of the key is what differentiates the key from
# password. If it has 0x then it is a key, otherwise it is a password).
#
# The corresponding user account entry in the config file will be:
#
#user=ninefingers:0xbc807ee29df3c9ffa736523fb2c4e8ee
# Or, equivalently, with open clear password (less secure):
#user=ninefingers:youhavetoberealistic
#

# SQLite database file name.
#
# The default file name is /var/db/turndb or /usr/local/var/db/turndb or
# /var/lib/turn/turndb.
#
#userdb=/var/db/turndb

# PostgreSQL database connection string in the case that you are using PostgreSQL
# as the user database.
# This database can be used for the long-term credential mechanism
# and it can store the secret value for secret-based timed authentication in TURN REST API.
# See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/libpq-connect.html for 8.x PostgreSQL
# versions connection string format, see
# http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING
# for 9.x and newer connection string formats.
#
#psql-userdb="host=<host> dbname=<database-name> user=<database-user> password=<database-user-password> connect_timeout=30"

# MySQL database connection string in the case that you are using MySQL
# as the user database.
# This database can be used for the long-term credential mechanism
# and it can store the secret value for secret-based timed authentication in TURN REST API.
#
# Optional connection string parameters for the secure communications (SSL):
# ca, capath, cert, key, cipher
# (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ssl-options.html for the
# command options description).
#
# Use the string format below (space separated parameters, all optional):
#
#mysql-userdb="host=<host> dbname=<database-name> user=<database-user> password=<database-user-password> port=<port> connect_timeout=<seconds> read_timeout=<seconds>"

# If you want to use an encrypted password in the MySQL connection string,
# then set the MySQL password encryption secret key file with this option.
#
# Warning: If this option is set, then the mysql password must be set in "mysql-userdb" in an encrypted format!
# If you want to use a cleartext password then do not set this option!
#
# This is the file path for the aes encrypted secret key used for password encryption.
#
#secret-key-file=/path/

# MongoDB database connection string in the case that you are using MongoDB
# as the user database.
# This database can be used for long-term credential mechanism
# and it can store the secret value for secret-based timed authentication in TURN REST API.
# Use the string format described at http://hergert.me/docs/mongo-c-driver/mongoc_uri.html
#
#mongo-userdb="mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]"

# Redis database connection string in the case that you are using Redis
# as the user database.
# This database can be used for long-term credential mechanism
# and it can store the secret value for secret-based timed authentication in TURN REST API.
# Use the string format below (space separated parameters, all optional):
#
#redis-userdb="ip=<ip-address> dbname=<database-number> password=<database-user-password> port=<port> connect_timeout=<seconds>"

# Redis status and statistics database connection string, if used (default - empty, no Redis stats DB used).
# This database keeps allocations status information, and it can be also used for publishing
# and delivering traffic and allocation event notifications.
# The connection string has the same parameters as redis-userdb connection string.
# Use the string format below (space separated parameters, all optional):
#
#redis-statsdb="ip=<ip-address> dbname=<database-number> password=<database-user-password> port=<port> connect_timeout=<seconds>"

# The default realm to be used for the users when no explicit
# origin/realm relationship is found in the database, or if the TURN
# server is not using any database (just the commands-line settings
# and the userdb file). Must be used with long-term credentials
# mechanism or with TURN REST API.
#
# Note: If the default realm is not specified, then realm falls back to the host domain name.
#       If the domain name string is empty, or set to '(None)', then it is initialized as an empty string.
#
realm=testdomain.com

# This flag sets the origin consistency
# check. Across the session, all requests must have the same
# main ORIGIN attribute value (if the ORIGIN was
# initially used by the session).
#
#check-origin-consistency

# Per-user allocation quota.
# default value is 0 (no quota, unlimited number of sessions per user).
# This option can also be set through the database, for a particular realm.
#
#user-quota=0

# Total allocation quota.
# default value is 0 (no quota).
# This option can also be set through the database, for a particular realm.
#
total-quota=100

# Max bytes-per-second bandwidth a TURN session is allowed to handle
# (input and output network streams are treated separately). Anything above
# that limit will be dropped or temporarily suppressed (within
# the available buffer limits).
# This option can also be set through the database, for a particular realm.
#
#max-bps=0

#
# Maximum server capacity.
# Total bytes-per-second bandwidth the TURN server is allowed to allocate
# for the sessions, combined (input and output network streams are treated separately).
#
#bps-capacity=0

# Uncomment if no UDP client listener is desired.
# By default UDP client listener is always started.
#
#no-udp

# Uncomment if no TCP client listener is desired.
# By default TCP client listener is always started.
#
#no-tcp

# Uncomment if no TLS client listener is desired.
# By default TLS client listener is always started.
#
#no-tls

# Uncomment if no DTLS client listener is desired.
# By default DTLS client listener is always started.
#
#no-dtls

# Uncomment if no UDP relay endpoints are allowed.
# By default UDP relay endpoints are enabled (like in RFC 5766).
#
#no-udp-relay

# Uncomment if no TCP relay endpoints are allowed.
# By default TCP relay endpoints are enabled (like in RFC 6062).
#
#no-tcp-relay

# Uncomment if extra security is desired,
# with nonce value having a limited lifetime.
# The nonce value is unique for a session.
# Set this option to limit the nonce lifetime.
# Set it to 0 for unlimited lifetime.
# It defaults to 600 secs (10 min) if no value is provided. After that delay,
# the client will get 438 error and will have to re-authenticate itself.
#
stale-nonce=600

# Uncomment if you want to set the maximum allocation
# time before it has to be refreshed.
# Default is 3600s.
#
#max-allocate-lifetime=3600


# Uncomment to set the lifetime for the channel.
# Default value is 600 secs (10 minutes).
# This value MUST not be changed for production purposes.
#
#channel-lifetime=600

# Uncomment to set the permission lifetime.
# Default to 300 secs (5 minutes).
# In production this value MUST not be changed,
# however it can be useful for test purposes.
#
#permission-lifetime=300

# Certificate file.
# Use an absolute path or path relative to the
# configuration file.
# Use PEM file format.
#
#cert=/usr/local/etc/turn_server_cert.pem

# Private key file.
# Use an absolute path or path relative to the
# configuration file.
# Use PEM file format.
#
#pkey=/usr/local/etc/turn_server_pkey.pem

# Private key file password, if it is in encoded format.
# This option has no default value.
#
#pkey-pwd=...

# Allowed OpenSSL cipher list for TLS/DTLS connections.
# Default value is "DEFAULT".
#
#cipher-list="DEFAULT"

# CA file in OpenSSL format.
# Forces TURN server to verify the client SSL certificates.
# By default this is not set: there is no default value and the client
# certificate is not checked.
#
# Example:
#CA-file=/etc/ssh/id_rsa.cert

# Curve name for EC ciphers, if supported by OpenSSL
# library (TLS and DTLS). The default value is prime256v1,
# if pre-OpenSSL 1.0.2 is used. With OpenSSL 1.0.2+,
# an optimal curve will be automatically calculated, if not defined
# by this option.
#
#ec-curve-name=prime256v1

# Use 566 bits predefined DH TLS key. Default size of the key is 2066.
#
#dh566

# Use 1066 bits predefined DH TLS key. Default size of the key is 2066.
#
#dh1066

# Use custom DH TLS key, stored in PEM format in the file.
# Flags --dh566 and --dh1066 are ignored when the DH key is taken from a file.
#
#dh-file=<DH-PEM-file-name>

# Flag to prevent stdout log messages.
# By default, all log messages go to both stdout and to
# the configured log file. With this option everything will
# go to the configured log only (unless the log file itself is stdout).
#
#no-stdout-log

# Option to set the log file name.
# By default, the turnserver tries to open a log file in
# /var/log, /var/tmp, /tmp and the current directory
# (Whichever file open operation succeeds first will be used).
# With this option you can set the definite log file name.
# The special names are "stdout" and "-" - they will force everything
# to the stdout. Also, the "syslog" name will force everything to
# the system log (syslog).
# In the runtime, the logfile can be reset with the SIGHUP signal
# to the turnserver process.
#
#log-file=/var/tmp/turn.log

# Option to redirect all log output into system log (syslog).
#
#syslog

# Set syslog facility for syslog messages
# Default values is ''.
#
#syslog-facility="LOG_LOCAL1"

# This flag means that no log file rollover will be used, and the log file
# name will be constructed as-is, without PID and date appendage.
# This option can be used, for example, together with the logrotate tool.
#
#simple-log

# Enable full ISO-8601 timestamp in all logs.
#new-log-timestamp

# Set timestamp format (in strftime(1) format). Depends on new-log-timestamp to be enabled.
#new-log-timestamp-format "%FT%T%z"

# Disabled by default binding logging in verbose log mode to avoid DoS attacks.
# Enable binding logging and UDP endpoint logs in verbose log mode.
#log-binding

# Option to set the "redirection" mode. The value of this option
# will be the address of the alternate server for UDP & TCP service in the form of
# <ip>[:<port>]. The server will send this value in the attribute
# ALTERNATE-SERVER, with error 300, on ALLOCATE request, to the client.
# Client will receive only values with the same address family
# as the client network endpoint address family.
# See RFC 5389 and RFC 5766 for the description of ALTERNATE-SERVER functionality.
# The client must use the obtained value for subsequent TURN communications.
# If more than one --alternate-server option is provided, then the functionality
# can be more accurately described as "load-balancing" than a mere "redirection".
# If the port number is omitted, then the default port
# number 3478 for the UDP/TCP protocols will be used.
# Colon (:) characters in IPv6 addresses may conflict with the syntax of
# the option. To alleviate this conflict, literal IPv6 addresses 
# in square brackets in such resource identifiers, for example:
# [2001:db8:85a3:8d3:1319:8a2e:370:7348]:3478 .
# Multiple alternate servers can be set. They will be used in the
# round-robin manner. All servers in the pool are considered of equal weight and
# the load will be distributed equally. For example, if you have 4 alternate servers,
# then each server will receive 25% of ALLOCATE requests. A alternate TURN server
# address can be used more than one time with the alternate-server option, so this
# can emulate "weighting" of the servers.
#
# Examples:
#alternate-server=1.2.3.4:5678
#alternate-server=11.22.33.44:56789
#alternate-server=5.6.7.8
#alternate-server=[2001:db8:85a3:8d3:1319:8a2e:370:7348]:3478

# Option to set alternative server for TLS & DTLS services in form of
# <ip>:<port>. If the port number is omitted, then the default port
# number 5349 for the TLS/DTLS protocols will be used. See the previous
# option for the functionality description.
#
# Examples:
#tls-alternate-server=1.2.3.4:5678
#tls-alternate-server=11.22.33.44:56789
#tls-alternate-server=[2001:db8:85a3:8d3:1319:8a2e:370:7348]:3478

# Option to suppress TURN functionality, only STUN requests will be processed.
# Run as STUN server only, all TURN requests will be ignored.
# By default, this option is NOT set.
#
#stun-only

# Option to hide software version. Enhance security when used in production.
# Revealing the specific software version of the agent through the
# SOFTWARE attribute might allow them to become more vulnerable to
# attacks against software that is known to contain security holes.
# Implementers SHOULD make usage of the SOFTWARE attribute a
# configurable option (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5389#section-16.1.2)
#
#no-software-attribute
```

(sniped at end due to character limits)

Comment: I don't have an easy answer, but for next steps you could turn on verbose logging, and run a packet capture on a client machine (and possibly the server as well) to see what's on the wire. If logging doesn't tell you, the packet capture might.